# If my textarea is empty do this with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Table,Button and a Textarea, When a user types inside the Textarea and click on the Button the text the user typed gets added to my table as a row. But if the Textarea is empty I dont want it to add empty rows in my table. How can I make it like that?

This is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CustomButton').click(function () {
            $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
            $('<tr/>', {
                click: function () {
                    $(this).remove()
                },
                html: $("<td />", {
                    html: $("#CustomQuestionTextArea").val(),
                    'data-attr-id': 5

                })
            })
        );
            return false;
        });
    });
</script
```

I guess it has to be like " If CustomquestionTextArea is "" return false else " add it to the table".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a pretty basic requirement, and you've already identified the pseudo-code to achieve what you want to do. I'm struggling to see how you can write jQuery code to bind event handlers, create and append new DOM elements, etc but can't implement a simple if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!$.trim($("#CustomQuestionTextArea").val())) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's more appropriate to check `.length`. This will return false if the value of the textbox is `"false"`, won't it?

Comment: `!!'false' === true` - so no, it won't. A string is only falsy if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can check length as follows:

```
if($.trim($("#CustomQuestionTextArea").val()).length > 0) {
   $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
   $('<tr/>', {
      click: function () {
         $(this).remove()
      },
      html: $("<td />", {
         html: $("#CustomQuestionTextArea").val(),
        'data-attr-id': 5
      })
   })
   // more stuff
}
```